# Insert the sin,tan and cos in the brain.h

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'll just post the operation code that i had in my .h

This is what I had currently and yea it's a coursework, but i think i'm the only person who doesn't have Java background in the class and the class ran pretty fast so all i can do is get more extra hour to understand or when i'm stuck i can only ask around.

```
-(double)performCalculation:(NSString *)operation
{
double result = 0;
    if ([operation isEqualToString:@"+"]){
        result = [self setOperand] + [self setOperand];
    }
    else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"-"]){
        double subtrahend = [self setOperand];
        result = [self setOperand] - subtrahend;
    }
    else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"*"]){
        result = [self setOperand] * [self setOperand];
    }
    else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"/"]){
        double divisor = [self setOperand];
        result = [self setOperand] / divisor;
    }
    else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"sin"]){
        double sin = sin([_operand.text doubleValue]);
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", sin];
    }
    [self getOperand:result];
    return result;

---------------------



i do know that it is very easy to insert the code in but i just had no idea how to do it and I am very new in this, please help!

Below is my code for the operation and the "sin" part is wrong but i don't know the correct way to apply it.


    else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"sin"]){
        double sine = sine(_operand.text doubleValue);
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sine(1)];
    }
```

Comment: This looks like the first assignment from a previous edition of Stanford's [CS 193P](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/).

Comment: Your post is a case study in how NOT to ask questions. You don't explain the background of what you are doing. You refer to "brain.h" in your title, but then never explain what that is. You reference brain.h, but the code you posted is clearly code from a .m or .c file, not a .h file. If this code is from a Stanford lecture, then tell your readers that! Also you say your code "is wrong" but don't say what the problem is. If you get a compiler error, tell us exactly which line gives the error, and copy and paste the error into your post.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"sin"]){
    double sine = sin([_operand.text doubleValue]);
    result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", sine];
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but this code should compile and run.

Comment: Don't you need to include the appropriate math include?  Eg, `#include <math.h>`.

Comment: @HotLicks If it's not included in different UIKit and Foundation frameworks then yes (and if those aren't included in your file).  Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
double sine = sine(_operand.text doubleValue);
result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sine(1)];
```

to

```
double sin = sin([_operand.text doubleValue]);
result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", sin];
```